# Проблемы с подключением Matrix Template Library Qt 4.8.5

Tags: c++, qt, boost

при подключении как в примере

```
#include <boost/numeric/mtl/mtl.hpp>
```

Вылетают синтактические ошибки в самом файле, как связать MTL с Qt?

OS openSUSE 13.1

```
/usr/include/boost/numeric/mtl/operation/mat_vec_mult.hpp:692: ошибка: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
/usr/include/boost/numeric/mtl/operation/mat_vec_mult.hpp:695: ошибка: expected primary-expression before ';' token
/usr/include/boost/numeric/mtl/matrix/ell_matrix.hpp:95: ошибка: 'int mtl::mat::ell_matrix<Value, Parameters>::size_type() const' conflicts with a previous declaration
/usr/include/boost/numeric/mtl/matrix/ell_matrix.hpp:83: ошибка: expected ';' before 'k'
/usr/include/boost/numeric/mtl/matrix/ell_matrix.hpp:83: ошибка: 'i' was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/boost/numeric/mtl/matrix/ell_matrix.hpp:83: ошибка: 'k' was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/boost/numeric/mtl/matrix/ell_matrix.hpp:113: ошибка: expected ';' before 'size'
```

Comment: Где ошибки? Какой пример?

Comment: http://www.simunova.com/node/144 ошибки привел выше